# Limiting loads with Json.load

Tags: python, json, limit

I am attempting to retrieve a dataset from a website utilizing Python. When the URL returns more than 10,000 records, it throws an error. Also, this url extract has a column when converted to dataframe called ‘Period’ I tried to apply filter to this column to takr upto latest data, but no leads. The following error occurs:

> HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: The given query is not allowed on this table. Please redefine your query so that it returns less than 10000 records.

Can we limit it to the last 100 values? I welcome any ideas.
Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd, json, ssl, certifi
from urllib.request import urlopen

def get_jsonparsed_data(url):
    response = urlopen(url, context=ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where()))
    data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(data)
  
  
  
  #Example:
  url1 = "********"
  df = pd.DataFrame(get_jsonparsed_data(url1)['value'])
```

Comment: Whatever `url` is would have to support a limit. If you control that URL, add the ability to it. If you don't, reach out to whoever does.

Comment: it's too late by the time you are using `json.loads`